# split() по строковому литералу без удаления разделителя

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пробую найти правильное регулярное выражение, никак не выходит.

Пример:

```
("текст1 текст2 'текст3 текст4' текст5 'текст6' текст7").split(<regexp>)
```

Необходимый результат:

```
[ "текст1 текст2 ", "'текст3 текст4'", " текст5 ", "'текст6'", " текст7"]
```

В тории должно было помочь выражение на подобии `"(?='.*')|(?<='.*')"`, но вторая часть жалуется на невозможность использования звёздочки.

Comment: Сплит по кавычке, а потом каждую чётную подстроку окавычить вручную. Ей-бо, проще, чем мозг морщить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
public static String[] splitIncludingDelimiters(String regex, String text) {
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
    int strt = 0;
    while(matcher.find()){
        list.add( text.substring(strt, matcher.start()) );
        list.add(matcher.group());
        strt = matcher.end();
    }

    if (strt < text.length()) list.add( text.substring(strt) );

    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

[Пример использования](https://ideone.com/Ao1ZJm):

```
String s = "текст1 текст2 'текст3 текст4' текст5 'текст6' текст7";
String regex = "'[^']*'";
for (String l : splitIncludingDelimiters(regex, s)) {
   System.out.println(l);
}
```

Результат:

```
текст1 текст2 
'текст3 текст4'
 текст5 
'текст6'
 текст7
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно и без регулярок, обычным циклом

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf(Split("текст1 текст2 'текст3 текст4' текст5 'текст6' текст7").toString());
}

static List<String> Split(String inp){
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    int ind = 0;
    while (ind < inp.length())
    {
        int start = ind;
        while (ind < inp.length() && inp.charAt(ind)!= '\'') ind++;
        ret.add(inp.substring(start, ind));
        start = ind;
        ind++;
        if (ind >= inp.length()) return ret;
        while (ind < inp.length() && inp.charAt(ind)!= '\'') ind++;
        ret.add(inp.substring(start, Math.min(ind + 1, inp.length())));
        ind++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Вывод

```
[текст1 текст2 , 'текст3 текст4',  текст5 , 'текст6',  текст7]
```

Comment: Для решения текущей задачи - да, но в общем случае может быть неизвестно, какой разделитель задан регулярным выражением.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ну вопрос то частный, а не общий. Ну и это быстрее просто будет работать, чем регулярки.